# Foundationpress, replace site title with logo

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using Foundation press and trying to replace the site title with a company logo. However, if no logo is uploaded, the site title should remain intact.

In functions.php I have:

```
function themename_custom_logo_setup() {
$defaults = array(
    'height'      => 100,
    'width'       => 100,
    'flex-height' => true,
    'flex-width'  => true,
    'header-text' => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', $defaults );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'themename_custom_logo_setup' );
```

And then in my header.php I have the following:

```
        <div class="site-title-bar title-bar" <?php foundationpress_title_bar_responsive_toggle() ?>>
        <div class="title-bar-left">
            <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="<?php foundationpress_mobile_menu_id(); ?>"></button>
            <div class="site-branding">

                <?php
                $logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
                $logo_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $logo_id, 'full' );

                if ( ! empty( $logo_image ) ) :
                ?>

                <span class="site-logo"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $logo_image[0] ); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"/></a></span>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </div><!-- site-branding -->
        </div><!-- title-bar-left -->
    </div><!-- site-title-bar title-bar -->
```

The option to insert a logo appears in the customiser. However, the logo is not being pulled into the site?

Comment: Have you checked what `get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' )` returns …? (Use `var_dump`.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to PHP, so not really sure how to use `var_dump`

Comment: `var_dump(get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' ));`